# Модуль time некорректно делает задержку в коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, время, sleep

Есть код:

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Арканоид")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=600, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 250, 250)
        self.x = 1
        self.y = -1
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 1
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.y = -1

        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 1
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -1


ball = Ball(canvas, "red")

while 1:
    try:
        ball.draw()
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        sleep(0.000000005)
    except:
        pass
```

Но time.sleep делает маленькую задержку, какую бы я не ставил.
Делал по уроку с YouTube, пишу в PyCharm

Comment: использовал для задержки a = 999 ** 9999, но интересно, почему же не работал модуль time?

Comment: `sleep` принимает время в секундах. Значение `0.000000005` (5 наносекунд) вероятно меньше разрешающей способности таймера.

Comment: 0.05 тоже не работает

Comment: Ваш код отлично работает на Linux. И правильно реагирует на задержку.

Comment: Хм.. А в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Не могу помочь с этим вопросом. Вы запускаете другой код?

Comment: time.sleep(0.005) делает неверную задержку, хотя в ютубе всё работало(на обучающем видео)

Comment: версии проверьте. Изменено в версии 3.5: теперь функция спит не менее секунды (см. PEP 475 для обоснования).или попробуйте заменить методом after() из ткинтера.

Comment: @Интик 3.7.4 - прекрасно спит менее секунды.

Comment: @Роман На вашем примере шарик летает. Если поставить 0.005 - то начинает передвигаться уже существенно медленнее. При 0.05 - еле ползёт. В общем, работает всё. Проверял под Windows.

Comment: @GrAnd в доках так написано https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: @Интик По вашей ссылке написано, что "Changed in version 3.5: The function now sleeps at least _secs_ even if the sleep is interrupted by a signal". Что переводится как  "Теперь функция спит как минимум _secs_ даже если сон прерывается сигналом". Где _secs_ - это аргумент функции. Нигде не написано, что _secs_ не может быть меньше единицы.

Comment: `0.05 тоже не работает` - как вы это определили? 5 миллисекунд - это очень маленькая задержка, вы глазом не отличите от 50 миллисекунд. `time.sleep(0.005) делает неверную задержку` - как вы это определили? 0.005 - это вообще микросекунды. Попробуйте поставить 0.05, 0.5 и 5 - будет заметна разница.